# How to determine optimal non-overlapping arrangement of hexagons based on minimal movement from geographical coordinates

Tags: mapping, coordinates, tessellation

I am trying to create a hexagon representation of assets that is similar to, but not the same as a hexbin map. Unlike the techniques I can easily find, I do not wish to bin the assets together but rather arrange each asset as an individual hexagon tile.
I would like to find an arrangement of the tiles that is closest to the geographical arrangement, but spreading the tiles out so there is no overlap. For example if I have this, I'd like it to turn into something like this:
[image]

What is the correct term for this technique, and does anyone have any suggestions on how best to do this?

Comment: What means _closest to the geographical arrangement_? How is the distance defined? For example, why is tile 5 not below tile 3 and adjacent to tile 4?